# Integral Inequality: Does multiplying integrand by $t$ maintain positivity?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $g: [0, 1]\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that, for all $x\in [0, 1]$, $\displaystyle\int_x^1 g(t) \ dt\geq 0$. I'd like to show that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 tg(t)\ dt\geq 0$.

Well, from, continuity, I know that $g(1)\geq 0$. If $g$ is always nonnegative, then certainly $tg(t)$ is always nonnegative as well. So I let $c$ be the largest root of $g$ in $[0, 1]$. This is where my proof got hand-wavy: I assumed the "worst case scenario" was that $g$ would be nonpositive on $[0, c]$, and then said that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 tg(t)\ dt=\displaystyle\int_0^c tg(t)\ dt+\displaystyle\int_c^1 tg(t)\ dt\geq \displaystyle\int_0^c cg(t)\ dt+\displaystyle\int_c^1 cg(t)\ dt=c\displaystyle\int_0^1 tg(t)\ dt\geq 0$ (the first inequality would hold since $g(x)$ is always nonpositive in the first pair of integrals and is always nonnegative in the second pair of integrals).

Is there a way to make my hand-wavy argument more rigorous? I'm suspecting that it's not necessarily the "worst case scenario."

Comment: You can integrate it with respect to x, and apply the Fubini theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe integration by parts?

define $G:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
G(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt
$$
so $G'(x)=g(x)$
$$
\int_0^1 tg(t)dt =\left[tG(t)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1G(t)dt =G(1)-G(\xi)=\int_{\xi}^1g(t) \ge 0
$$

Comment: Oh, the penultimate equality is from the Mean Value Theorem for integrals, right?

Comment: yes, sorry, i hoped the squiggle (Greek xi $\xi$) would save explanation!